# Sort a list by a key and get the value out without recomputing

Tags: python, sorting

I have a `score` function, and I want to sort a list according to it.

Ordinarily, this is easy (just get `sorted(l, key=score)`), but I need the scores later in the code, and `score` is computationally expensive (so I want to avoid scoring twice).

---

Here's my current code:

```
scores= map(score, l)
new_l= [el for i,el in sorted(enumerate(l), key=lambda (i,el): scores[i])]
```

This works, but is a bit confusing and not particularly readable.

What's the best way to achieve this?

Comment: why `key=lambda i,el:`?

Comment: @PadraicCunningham sorry, it's actually `(i,el)`, for unpacking the tuple

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Create a dictionary, with keys as your elements from `l` and the corresponding values will be the `scores`

```
>>> scores = {el: score(el) for el in l}
```

And then use `scores.get` for the `key`, like this

```
>>> sorted(l, key=scores.get)
```

**Note:** This technique will work only if the elements of `l` are hashable.

Answer (score 3):

[`functools.lru_cache`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functools.html#functools.lru_cache) may be useful in here. As in the docs:

> Decorator to wrap a function with a memoizing callable that saves up to the maxsize most recent calls. It can save time when an expensive or I/O bound function is periodically called with the same arguments.

simply, add the `lru_cache` to your function:

```
@lru_cache(maxsize=32)
def score(i):
    ...
```